# Instatiated objects from the same prefab share a position?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm starting a simple JRPG: generating a party from a group of prefabs, then moving each into position by changing their transform. But seeing a strange one where 3 goblins spawned from the same prefab are moving to exactly the same position. The other objects instantiated from different objects are moving correctly.

In the player, I can move the goblins by changing their transform, and they are separate. However the prefab itself is changing position to match the 'last' goblin spawned

Any hints? Am I somehow instantiating them to a common object?

Objects created and positioned in PartyManager:

```
public bool playerParty = true;
public GameObject[] party=new GameObject[4]; 

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    for (int i=0; i<party.Length; i++){
        GameObject character = Instantiate(party[i],this.gameObject.transform);
    }
    positionCharacters();
}


void positionCharacters(){
    float facing = -1.0f;
    if(playerParty) facing=1.0f;
    
    for (int i=0; i<party.Length; i++){
        party[i].transform.localPosition = new Vector3(-0.3f*i*facing, -0.05f*i,-0.1f*i);
        print(party[i]+" moved to "+party[i].transform.localPosition);
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't seem to be storing references to the instantiated characters, `GameObject character` just goes out of scope immediately. If you put three references to the same object into `GameObject[] party` you shouldn't be surprised only the last set position is used.

Comment: Thank you - that did it. On instantiate, I am now saving party[i] = character; This is now giving me unique copies with separate locations.

Comment: Feel free to accept this answer if you found it helpful.